# Count lines and group by prefix word

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line

I want to count number of lines in a document and group it by the prefix word. Prefix is a set of alphanumeric characters delimited by first underscore. I don't care much about sorting them but it would be nice to list them descending by number of occurrences.

The file looks like this:

```
prefix1_data1
prefix1_data2_a
differentPrefix_data3
prefix1_data2_b
differentPrefix_data5
prefix2_data4
differentPrefix_data5
```

The output should be the following:

```
prefix1           3
differentPrefix   3
prefix2           1
```

I already did this in python but I am curious if it is possible to do this more efficient using command line or bash script? `uniq` command has `-c` and `-w` options but the length of prefix may vary.

Comment: `cut -d'_' -f1 <inputfile| sort |uniq -c`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk -F_ '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

The field separator is set to `_`.

An array `a` is filled with all first element, with their associated count.

When the file is parsed the array content  is printed

Answer (score 7):

The solution using combination of `sed`, `sort` and `uniq` commands:

```
sed -rn 's/^([^_]+)_.*/\1/p' testfile | sort | uniq -c
```

The output:

```
3 differentPrefix
3 prefix1
1 prefix2
```

---

`^([^_]+)_` - matches a sub-string(prefix, containing any characters except `_`) from the start of the string to the first occurrence of underscore `_`

Comment: You can use shorter expression for matching prefix: `^([^_]+).*`

Answer (score 2):

I like RomanPerekhrest's answer.  It's more concise.  Here is a small change to make it even more concise by using cut in place of sed.

```
cut -d_ -f1 testfile | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in following manner, testfile is file with contents mentioned above.

```
printf %-20s%d"\n" prefix1 $(cat testfile|grep "^prefix1" | wc -l)
printf %-20s%d"\n" differentPrefix $(cat testfile|grep "^differentPrefix" | wc -l)
printf %-20s%d"\n" prefix2 $(cat testfile|grep "^prefix2" | wc -l)
```

so you can check this with your code and check which one's more efficient.